# Store timestamp from vimeo

Tags: database, reactjs, api, vimeo, vimeo-player

I currently have an iframe on my site with a vimeo player.
What I need is: the moment the user pauses the video or closes, store the timestamp so that in another when the user returns to the video, it returns at the point of the stored timestamp. Like Netflix video player.
It's possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the timestamp is possible with [Vimeo's Player Api](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js). Making use of the [timeupdate](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#timeupdate) listener, the current playback position can be saved. As for how the timestamp is saved, there are many different options (you could store the data [client side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage), [server side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction), in a db, etc...). Then when a user returns to the page you could check if a timestamp exists and set the video's playback position accordingly with [setCurrentTime()](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#setcurrenttimeseconds-number-promisenumber-rangeerrorerror)